# (Heroku) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I've only encountered this problem on Heroku (on my computer it starts without errors) I'm looking for a solution to this problem and I look forward to helping with this problem!

```
/app/index.js:50
let channel = client.channels.cache.Get(config.ChannelId);
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Get')
at Timeout.UpdateInfo [as _onTimeout] (/app/index.js:50:41)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

Comment: Typo: it needs to be `get` with a small 'g'

Comment: i tried this - same problem